# Sort a vector of vectors in parallel using a conditional variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector, mutex

I am trying to sort a NxN vector of vectors in parallel by dispatching N threads for each vector. I want to display the vector of vectors every time each vector within the vector of vectors has been sorted. Please see example below.

Initially

```
2,1,3,4
1,3,2,4
3,4,1,2
3,2,1,4
```

Sorting
.
.
Display

```
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
1,4,3,2
2,3,1,4
```

.
.
Sorting
.
.

```
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
1,3,4,2
2,1,3,4
```

... and so on..

I have some executable code to do this sequentuially and I have tried to do this using a conditional variable but I can't get it to work with the conditional variable at all.

Below is the sequential code which is working in terms of sorting the vector of vectors but it can't produce the display that I desire.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <ctime> 
#include <random>


std::vector<int> row;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> block;
int cols = 10;
auto rng = std::default_random_engine{};


void init()
{

        srand((unsigned)time(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int j;
            j = (rand() % 100) + 1;
            row.push_back(j);
    }

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {

                std::vector<int> y;
                std::shuffle(std::begin(row), std::end(row), rng);
                y = row;
                block.push_back(y);
            }

    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            std::cout << block[i][j] << ", "; 

        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

void Sort(std::vector<int> &Row)
{

        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (Row[i] < Row[j])
                {
                    int temp = Row[i];
                    Row[i] = Row[j];
                    Row[j ] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

}

void display()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            std::cout << block[i][j] << ", ";

        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}


int main() {

    std::cout << "test\n";
    init();
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "Sorting";
    std::cout << "\n";
    for(int i =0; i < cols; i++)    
        Sort(block[i]);
    std::cout << "\n";
    display();
    std::cout << "Sorted";
    getchar();
}
```

The output for the above code is as follows

```
98, 15, 13, 10, 44, 63, 85, 93, 39, 43,
93, 10, 15, 13, 43, 44, 39, 63, 85, 98,
93, 13, 63, 15, 43, 85, 98, 39, 44, 10,
44, 98, 39, 85, 13, 10, 63, 43, 93, 15,
10, 98, 63, 93, 85, 44, 39, 15, 13, 43,
63, 39, 44, 98, 93, 15, 43, 85, 13, 10,
43, 63, 93, 44, 15, 39, 10, 85, 98, 13,
39, 85, 13, 63, 44, 98, 93, 43, 10, 15,
39, 44, 85, 63, 43, 93, 98, 10, 15, 13,
15, 43, 44, 93, 85, 39, 63, 10, 98, 13,

Sorting

10, 13, 15, 39, 43, 44, 63, 85, 93, 98,
10, 13, 15, 39, 43, 44, 63, 85, 93, 98,
10, 13, 15, 39, 43, 44, 63, 85, 93, 98,
10, 13, 15, 39, 43, 44, 63, 85, 93, 98,
10, 13, 15, 39, 43, 44, 63, 85, 93, 98,
10, 13, 15, 39, 43, 44, 63, 85, 93, 98,
10, 13, 15, 39, 43, 44, 63, 85, 93, 98,
10, 13, 15, 39, 43, 44, 63, 85, 93, 98,
10, 13, 15, 39, 43, 44, 63, 85, 93, 98,
10, 13, 15, 39, 43, 44, 63, 85, 93, 98,
Sorted
```

The multi-threaded approach that I have taken below is not working as expected. I have tried a number of things but to no success.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <thread>
#include<vector>
#include <ctime> 
#include <mutex>
#include<chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <deque>
#include <condition_variable>

std::deque<int> q;
std::mutex mu;
std::condition_variable cond;
int count = 4;
std::vector<int> x{ 5,2,1,3,4 };
std::vector<std::vector<int>> xx;
void init() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        xx.push_back(x);
    }
}

void display()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < xx.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < xx[i].size(); j++)
        {
            std::cout << xx[i][j] << " ,";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

}

bool isSorted(int z)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (xx[z][i] > xx[z][i + 1])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void function_1(int &row)
{

    while (!isSorted(row))
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (xx[row][i] > xx[row][i + 1])
            {
                int temp = xx[row][i];
                xx[row][i] = xx[row][i + 1];
                xx[row][i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
        count--;
        locker.unlock();
        cond.notify_one();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

    }
}

void function_2() {
    int data = 0;
    while (data != 1)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
        cond.wait(locker, []() {return (count == 0); });
        q.clear();
        display();
        count = 4;
        locker.unlock();

    }
}

int main()
{
    init();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        std::thread *t1 = new std::thread(function_1, std::ref(i));
    }
    std::thread t2(function_2);
    //  t2.join();
    std::cout << " all threads done";
    getchar();
}
```

The output is like this (when compiled with g++ and c++11 standards set):

```
main.cpp: In function 'void display()':
main.cpp:27:23: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     for (int i = 0; i < xx.size(); i++)
                     ~~^~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:29:27: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
         for (int j = 0; j < xx[i].size(); j++)
                         ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:89:22: warning: unused variable 't1' [-Wunused-variable]
         std::thread *t1 = new std::thread(function_1, std::ref(i));
                      ^~
terminate called without an active exception
 all threads done5 ,2 ,1 ,3 ,4 ,
5 ,2 ,1 ,3 ,4 ,
2 ,1 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,
2 ,1 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,
1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,
```

Here's [the demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a32ad25ea40cade5).

Comment: Since c++17, [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) can accept an [execution policy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) which can be used to parallelize the sorting operation.

Comment: I fixed that, sorry

Comment: I am working with c++11

Comment: `std::thread` should be [detached](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) or [joined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join). You should store your threads into a vector and join to them to know when they are done doing their work. It also seems that the worker threads only work when they own the global mutex, which means that they will only be able to work one at a time. This negates any advantage of multithreading.

Comment: do you want to display the "current state of play" across all sub-vectors (which will require a mega-lock) or display the last state but with just the newly sorted vector changed?

Comment: @user8981117 Sorry, I cannot [compile you code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20b90515c0f25178). Can you please fix that first.

Comment: @RichardHodges I want to display the current state of play across all sub-vectors.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I am not trying to optimize the work here but rather, I am using multi threading to be able to visualize my sorting algorithm.

Comment: @user0042 I am using visual studio 2017 and my code compiles just fine. It does crash during run time though but that is a different issue from the one that you are suggesting.

Comment: @user8981117 Then [edit] your question please to add these missing parts of information. I just tried to nudge you into the right direction with my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue you had was to pass `i` from main as a reference. All the threads would share the `4` that the loop exited with.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    std::thread *t1 = new std::thread(function_1, std::ref(i)); //same i !!
}
```

and then:

```
void function_1(int &row)...
```

Also not that `i+1` is 5 before you exit the loop so it is out of range:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (xx[z][i] > xx[z][i + 1])
        return false;
}
```

Then, as was pointed out, it is just a matter of joining the threads to wait for a finish. This seems to work ok but I would have done this with a class so there would be no globals.

I left the includes out...

```
std::mutex mu;
std::vector<int> x{ 5,2,1,3,4 };
std::vector<std::vector<int>> xx;

void init() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        xx.push_back(x);
    }
}

void display( int in )
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < xx.size(); i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < xx[i].size(); j++)
        {
            std::cout << xx[i][j] << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << " id: " << in << "\n";
}

bool isSorted( int z )
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (xx[z][i] > xx[z][i + 1])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void function_1( int row )
{
    for( ; ! isSorted(row); )
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (xx[row][i] > xx[row][i + 1])
            {
                int temp = xx[row][i];
                xx[row][i] = xx[row][i + 1];
                xx[row][i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
        display( row );
        locker.unlock( );
    }
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
    std::cout << "end: " << row << std::endl;
    locker.unlock( );

}

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::thread* > threads;
    init();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
        threads.push_back( new std::thread( function_1, i ) );
        std::cout << "started: " << i << std::endl;
        locker.unlock( );
    }
    for( auto thread : threads )
        thread->join( );

    std::cout << " all threads done";
    return 0;
}
```